# How to make a graph in latex?

Tags: graphics, graphs

Someone help me to make the following graph in latex. I am a beginner or practically new to latex graphics.[image]

Comment: There's an rror on this draawing: the abscissa of the intersection is not 400/45, but 4000/45=800/9.

Comment: Yes, I had that error. In the accounts I made I have 4000/45 and I just put something else.

Comment: Have you looked at the pgfplots package?

Answer (score 2):

If you compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.1]
    \coordinate (i) at (800/9,2600/27);
    \coordinate (j) at (800/9,0);
    \draw (-5,0)--(100,0);
    \draw (0,-5)--(0,125);
    \draw[thick,domain=0:100] plot (\x,{(7*\x/4-3*(\x/10)*(\x/10)/4});
    \draw[thick,domain=0:100] plot (\x,{(3*\x/4+3*(\x/10)*(\x/10)/8});
    \draw[dashed] (j)--(i);
    \node[above left] at (60,78) {$7000x-30x^2$};
    \node[above left] at (100,112) {$3000x+15x^2$};
    \node at (50,60) {$A$};
    \node at (i) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node[below left] at (0,0) {$0$};
    \node[below] at (j) {$\frac{800}9$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain to me how you did it or in what program, or what pdf's I use to do it. I really would like to learn how to make these types of graphs.

Comment: I did it using [TikZ](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package).